# Проблема с постинкрементом в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

```
int x = 0;
x = x++;
cout << x; // 1
```

Если я не ошибаюсь, то в x должно записаться 0 а потом только увеличить значение.
Кто объяснит что за дела?

[image]

Писал в Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Что Вас смутило?

Comment: вы ошибаетесь (оператор '=' имеет низший приоритет) и даже если бы это работало так как вы думали то в итоге x бы все равно увеличился на 1.

Comment: Никакой проблемы нет. Это ожидаемое поведение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, там должен быть 0, но до С++17 это вызывало неопределенное поведение (см. 20 пункт [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)).

Похоже в MSVC это еще не исправили.

Что интересно, GCC и Clang ругаются на этот код, но таки выводят `0`.

Comment: Почему там должен был 0, если х инкрементируется перед выводом? (и не важно, до присвоения или после)

Comment: @Эникейщик Сначала запоминается значение `x`. Потом `x` инкрементируется. Потом то запомненное значение (то есть `0`) присваивается `x`. С cppreference: "In every ... assignment expression `E1=E2` ..., every value computation and side-effect of `E2` is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of `E1`.

Comment: Не подтверждаю, в visual studio 2017 пофикшено ( х = 0), возможно у ТС более ранняя версия. Дополнительно на это ругается анализатор PVS, сама студия даже с w4 считает код валидным. P.S. если в студии врубить 14й стандарт, то ожидаемо х = 1, так что всё исправлено как и надо только для с++17 =)